# Problem with extracting price in a string

Tags: java, regex, string, currency

```
String quantity = cboAmount.getSelectedItem().toString();
String product = cboProduct.getSelectedItem().toString();

String price = product.replaceAll("(\\d+(?:\\.\\d{1,2})?)", "");

textareaOrder.setText(price);
```

I want to extract the price from some text in a combobox, I've googled people's solutions but they all didn't work, the one in the example displays everything but the price. I don't know if I'm missing something here. The text in the combobox is written like this "Orange: 2.00" if that matters.

Tried to extract price from a string but didn't get it

Comment: So you write a regex for the price, but then you replace the thing that you found with an empty String?

Comment: `price.replace("Orange: ", "")`

Comment: `String price = product.replaceAll(".*?(\\d+(?:\\.\\d{1,2})?)", "$1");` but you shouldn't be bundling the two items together. It should be `JComboBox<Product>`, allowing you to extract the floating point price separately from the instance in the model

Comment: Do not remove, *extract*.

Answer (score -1):

**note: Use regex to capture the prices**

[Java Regex Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String priceString = "Orange: 2.00";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d+");
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(priceString);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).